# copyIndex() inside a listKeys()

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-stream-analytics

We're trying to deploy an ARM template which deploys a Stream Analytics job with *n* Event Hubs outputs depending on an input parameter.
Right now we're having success with all but the `listKeys()` function inside the `outputs` property copy loop function which gets each Event Hub's primary keys:

```
"sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('clientEventHubNamespace'), parameters('clients')[copyIndex('outputs')].id, variables('clientEventHubClientSharedAccessName')), '2015-08-01').primaryKey]"
```

We get the error:

> 17:44:31 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template
>   validation failed: 'The template resource
>   'tailor-router-axgf7t3gtspue' at line '129' and column '10' is not
>   valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this
>   location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy
>   specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details..
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage
>   details.'.

However, if we change this to be a specific index:

```
"sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('clientEventHubNamespace'), parameters('clients')[0].id, variables('clientEventHubClientSharedAccessName')), '2015-08-01').primaryKey]"
```

it works.

Is `copyIndex('propertyName')` inside a `listKeys()` a supported function?
If not, is there a workaround that would achieve the same effect?

Kind regards,

Nick

---

Stream Analytics job resource definition:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/StreamingJobs",
  "name": "[variables('routerStreamAnalyticsName')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [ "clientsEventHubCopy" ],
  "tags": {
    "boundedContext": "[variables('boundedContextName')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "name": "[parameters('routerStreamAnalyticsSkuTier')]"
    },
    "outputErrorPolicy": "drop",
    "eventsOutOfOrderPolicy": "adjust",
    "eventsOutOfOrderMaxDelayInSeconds": 0,
    "eventsLateArrivalMaxDelayInSeconds": 5,
    "dataLocale": "en-US",
    "compatibilityLevel": "1.0",
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "input0",
        "properties": {
          "type": "stream",
          "serialization": {
            "type": "Avro"
          },
          "datasource": {
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/EventHub",
            "properties": {
              "serviceBusNamespace": "[parameters('input0EventHubNamespace')]",
              "sharedAccessPolicyName": "[parameters('input0EventHubSharedAccessPolicyName')]",
              "sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[parameters('input0EventHubSharedAccessPolicyKey')]",
              "eventHubName": "[parameters('input0EventHubName')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "transformation": {
      "name": "routing",
      "properties": {
        "streamingUnits": "[parameters('routerStreamAnalyticsSkuTier')]",
        "query": "omitted"
      }
    },
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "outputs",
        "count": "[length(parameters('clients'))]",
        "input": {
          "name": "[parameters('clients')[copyIndex('outputs')].id]",
          "properties": {
            "datasource": {
              "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/EventHub",
              "properties": {
                "serviceBusNamespace": "[variables('clientEventHubNamespace')]",
                "sharedAccessPolicyName": "[variables('clientEventHubClientSharedAccessName')]",
                "sharedAccessPolicyKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', variables('clientEventHubNamespace'), parameters('clients')[copyIndex('outputs')].id, variables('clientEventHubClientSharedAccessName')), '2015-08-01').primaryKey]",
                "eventHubName": "[parameters('clients')[copyIndex('outputs')].id]"
              }
            },
            "serialization": {
              "type": "Avro"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: ``Is copyIndex('propertyName') inside a listKeys() a supported function? If not, is there a workaround that would achieve the same effect?`` I do a test and same error appear, I will continue to study this issue. Besides, as a workaround, you could try to create multiple separate sections for outputs.

Comment: Thanks @FredHan-MSFT
Could you please elaborate on 'multiple separate sections for outputs'?

Comment: ``We're trying to deploy an ARM template which deploys a Stream Analytics job with n Event Hubs outputs`` try to separately define for these n Event Hubs outputs.

Comment: Thanks @FredHan-MSFT, but the reason we're using the `copy` function in the first place is so that we can provide an array of 'clients' as an input parameter and not have to change the template every time we add a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this and sorry for the inconvenience.
I just talked to the ARM team, we had an issue when copyindex was inside the index tags eg 'array[copyindex()]'. It should be fixed now.

Let us know how it goes.

Thanks,

JS - Azure Stream Analytics